# How to set State in React for different scenarios based on the data that is available?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set up primary and secondary default sorting options based on different tables that I have. One of the table that I have is called "Ranked category" which has the column "Rank" in it. In this table, I need to sort my table data in ascending order by type "rank":

**Ranked Category**

```
Rank |   Title    | Type
-------------------------
 2   |  Microsoft | Technical assistance
 3   |  Facebook  | Project
 1   |  Amazon    | Plan
```

The other table is called "Plan Category". In this table, the only differene is that it does not contain the column "Rank" so the data needs to be sorted by the "Title" column:

**Plan Category**

```
Title  | Type
--------------
IBM    | Project
Uber   | Technical assistance
Lyft   | Plan
```

Following is the payload that I recieve from the rest call:

```
payload = [
  0: {categoryTitle: "Microsoft", categoryType: "Technical assistance", rank: 2, category: "Ranked", …}
  1: {categoryTitle: "Facebook", categoryType: "Project", rank: 3, category: "Ranked", …}
  2: {categoryTitle: "Amazon", categoryType: "Plan", rank: 1, category: "Ranked", …}
  3: {categoryTitle: "IBM", categoryType: "Project", rank: undefined, category: "Plan", …}
  4: {categoryTitle: "Uber", categoryType: "Technical assistance", rank: undefined, category: "Plan", …}
  5: {categoryTitle: "Lyft", categoryType: "Plan", rank: undefined, category: "Plan", …}
]
```

This is what I have tried and looks like it overwrites the previous state and only sorts the data by title because I am seeing both tables sorted by title only.

Can someone help me resolve this issue?

```
_.map(payload, item => {
  if(item.category === 'Ranked') {
    result = _.sortBy(payload, 'rank');
  } else {
    result = _.sortBy(payload, 'categoryTitle');
  }
})

this.setState({ data: result })
```

## **Desired output**

The "*Ranked Category*" table is sorted by *rank*, and the "*Plan Category*" table is sorted by *title*:

**Ranked Category**

```
Rank |   Title    | Type
-------------------------
 1   |  Amazon    | Plan
 2   |  Microsoft | Technical assistance
 3   |  Facebook  | Project
```

**Plan Category**

```
Title  | Type
--------------
IBM    | Project
Lyft   | Plan
Uber   | Technical assistance
```

Comment: You're looping over all your items in `payload` but then sorting the entire `payload` array with each iteration. Do you want to end up with one array, where "Ranked" items are sorted amongst themselves, followed by "categoryTitle" items also sorted amongst themselves?

Comment: Thanks for the response @Barryman9000. Do you think it can be work with just one array where items that have rank are sorted by rank and those that do not have rank can be sorted by title instead?

Comment: I just read your msg again @Barryman9000 and yes, that's exactly what I am looking for. Just one array and items that have rank are sorted by rank and those that do not are sorted by categoryTitle.

Comment: You can, but if you have control over the API this is something I'd handle on the back end.

Comment: I don't have control over the api. Can you show me how to do it in react on the front end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so basically you need to filter by 2 attributes, sort each separate array, and re-merge?

```
[unorderedArray] =>
[orderedByRank] [orderedByTitle] =>
[...orderedByRank, ...orderedByTitle]
```

I think the spread syntax is something you might want to use here.

this is one way to accomplish that... but far from the most efficient.

```
const payload = [
   {categoryTitle: "Microsoft", categoryType: "Technical assistance", rank: 2, category: "Ranked" },
   {categoryTitle: "Facebook", categoryType: "Project", rank: 3, category: "Ranked" },
   {categoryTitle: "Amazon", categoryType: "Plan", rank: 1, category: "Ranked"},
  {categoryTitle: "IBM", categoryType: "Project", rank: undefined, category: "Plan"},
  {categoryTitle: "Uber", categoryType: "Technical assistance", rank: undefined, category: "Plan"},
  {categoryTitle: "Lyft", categoryType: "Plan", rank: undefined, category: "Plan"}
];
function compareRank(a,b){
  const rankA = a.rank || 999;
  const rankB = b.rank || 999;
  if(rankA>rankB){return 1}
  else if(rankA<rankB){return -1} 
  else{return 0}
}
function compareTitles(a,b)
  {
  let nameA = a.categoryTitle.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  let nameB = b.categoryTitle.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase

  if (nameA < nameB) {return -1;}
  else if (nameA > nameB) { return 1;}
  else{ return 0;}
  }

const filteredPayloadTitle = payload.filter(x=>!x.rank);
const filteredPayloadRank = payload.filter(x=>x.rank != undefined);
console.log(filteredPayloadTitle);
const sortedPayloadByTitle = filteredPayloadTitle.sort((x,y)=>compareTitles(x,y));
const sortedPayloadByRank  = filteredPayloadRank.sort((x,y)=>compareRank(x,y));
const finalArray=[];
sortedPayloadByRank.forEach(x=>finalArray.push(x));
sortedPayloadByTitle.forEach(x=>finalArray.push(x));
console.log(finalArray);
```

link to working codepen.io
https://codepen.io/altruios/pen/poyPjBK?editors=1012

Comment: Thank you so much altruios. I just tested your solution in my app and it worked out like a charm. Exactly what I needed. Appreciate your help and time.

Comment: again, there are cleverer ways to do that. and that's pretty brittle considering the functions that sort aren't robust. there's clearly a much better way to do that than what I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not super performant but it works and it's easy enough to read

```
const sorter = (arr, key) => arr.sort((a,b) => a[key] > b[key] ? 1 : -1)


const multiSorter = (arr) => {
    let payloads = [[],[]]

    // first separate them into two arrays
    arr.forEach(item => {
        item.rank !== undefined ? payloads[0].push(item) : payloads[1].push(item)
    })

    // sort each and flatten
    return payloads.map(item => 
        item[0].rank !== undefined ? 
          sorter(item, "rank") : 
          sorter(item, 'categoryTitle')).flat()
}

multiSorter(payloads)
```

Result:

```
0: {categoryTitle: "Amazon", categoryType: "Plan", rank: 1, category: "Ranked"}
1: {categoryTitle: "Microsoft", categoryType: "Technical assistance", rank: 2, category: "Ranked"}
2: {categoryTitle: "Facebook", categoryType: "Project", rank: 3, category: "Ranked"}
3: {categoryTitle: "IBM", categoryType: "Project", rank: undefined, category: "Plan"}
4: {categoryTitle: "Lyft", categoryType: "Plan", rank: undefined, category: "Plan"}
5: {categoryTitle: "Uber", categoryType: "Technical assistance", rank: undefined, category: "Plan"}
```

Comment: This is great and also very neat! Thank you so much Barryman9000.